# Safari for OS X displaying wrong favicon

Tags: macos, safari

I am using Safari 9.0.3 on OS X 10.11.9 and have only recently noticed Safari displaying the wrong favicon for some websites.

In one instance, Safari uses the Facebook icon for Messenger despite the Messenger icon being used in the head section of the page source.

I tried deleting the WebpageIcons.db file from Safari's Library folder, and I have cleared Safari history and website data across all my devices.

The Facebook icon still loads.

Any ideas?

Edit: To clarify, the proper Messenger.com icon appears in the bookmarks menu and the bookmarks editor window. However, the Facebook.com icon is used in the Smart Search Field.

Screenshot of Safari using the wrong favicon:
[image: Safari screenshot]

Facebook's Messenger.com icon:

[image: Messenger icon]

Comment: Could you upload snippets of screen shots showing the results you see? Also, what precisely is your desired goal? Are you asking if this is a bug? Asking other to verify they see what you see?

Comment: Revised my question to include a screenshot of Safari using the Facebook icon in the Smart Search Field following the icon it is meant to use. I assume it's a bug but don't know if it's unique to my situation.

Comment: You are not the only one having the problem. I am having the same issue. Not a Facebook icon. Whatever this ugly E icon is. I'm not sure what site it is for. But it is coming up for several sites in my fav panel. As you can see it is the correct favicon in the address bar. [![Bookmark Panel](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2BUBm.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2BUBm.png) I have not found a solution for the problem. I have deleted and re-created the bookmark (no joy). I have reset the favicon cache. I have deleted the ~/Library/Safari/WebpageIcons.db. Nothing has fixed it so far.

Comment: [i asked and answered a similar question just today here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/294606/how-to-get-icons-in-safari-favorites-to-display-correctly/294633#294633)

Answer (score 6):

You aren't actually looking at the favicon, but rather the **Touch Icon**. You can find your Touch Icons in `~/Library/Safari/Touch Icons Cache/` and then look in the `Images/` folder to find the actual image files.

[image: Touch Icons Cache]

Your choice here is you can replace the offending image with the one you want and restart Safari to have it load that, or just trash the whole Touch Icons Cache folder entirely.

Comment: Is there a GUI-way of this - which I obviously prefer?

Answer (score 1):

There are many complicated rules on what icon file gets displayed in a browser, depending on the combination of "link" HTML tag used and browser/OS version.
The following will help to understand better (in order of preference):
- search for Favicon on Wikipedia
- http://blog.iconfactory.com/2015/11/the-new-favicon/
- http://evotec.pl/mac-os-x-yosemite-missing-favicons-in-safari-8/

Comment: Facebook.com and Messenger.com use different favicon as specified in the head section of the page markup. However, the 2 websites appear to have the same icon in Safari's bookmarks.