# Why won't my website favicon show up in Safari favorites bar automatically?

Tags: macos, safari

My website was not displaying the Favicon in the menu bar as in this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/294606/how-to-get-icons-in-safari-favorites-aka-favicons-to-display-correctly). See the copied image below but in this case we would be Google and trying to get that icon to populate without user intervention.

[image: image from other question]

I am aware that locally, these favicon files re stored in `~/Library/Safari/Touch Icons Cache/Images/` however I was trying to figure out where Safari pulls the `.png` file from to cache initially.

As noted in one of the answers to the referenced question, it is not practical to ask a site to fix this, therefore I wanted to know how to fix the issue as the website publisher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my question is to upload a `Favicon.png` file to the root directory of my website as such. This is where Safari pulls the favicon to show in the favorites bar.

[image]